# Rails 3.1 Asset StyleSheet sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

i have 'reset.css' and added it to app/assets/stylesheets, and application.css automatically includes it in my every pages. but then I added 'pages' controller, the reset.css is bumped to last.

can i have some sort of control in organizing my css in assets directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change loading order in application.css

```
/*
*= require reset
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```